# How is building an array of objects working? I'm stuck with this example

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand some code that is for an ESP32 EPaper module(TTGO T5 V2.2). This program makes use of the Button2 library for handling events when one of the three buttons is pressed. It initializes an object for each button and stores it in an array of pointers. when I want to compile the code, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Button2::Button2()'
```

(info: Button2 *pBtns = nullptr; args = 3; )
The codeline where the error occures is:

```
pBtns = new Button2 [args];
```

So far I understood, should this line reserve the memory on the heap for that new object. So why should there be a function and what's the purpose of it?

I tried so far using a fixed array size and use a sniplet from some example found somewhere on the internet:

```
//Button2 pBtns[5] = {nullptr,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr};
//Button2 pBtns[5];
//Button2* pBtns = static_cast<Button2*>( ::operator new ( sizeof(Button2) * (sizeof(g_btns) / sizeof(g_btns[0]))));
//  g_btns[] is the array of gpio pins of the buttons
```

Due to the lack of examples I have still no clue if I am missing something, but the "no matching function for call"-error hints to a problem with the object itself, if I'm not wrong ...

```
// in Button2.h:

class Button2 {
  private:
    .// some private defs ...
  public:
    Button2(byte attachTo, byte buttonMode = INPUT_PULLUP, unsigned int debounceTimeout = DEBOUNCE_MS);
    .// some methods here ...
    bool operator==(Button2 &rhs);

    void loop();
};


// in program code:

#define BUTTONS_MAP {37,38,39}

Button2 *pBtns = nullptr;
uint8_t g_btns[] =  BUTTONS_MAP;

void button_init()
{
    uint8_t args = sizeof(g_btns) / sizeof(g_btns[0]);
    pBtns = new Button2 [args];   //<<<<<<< COMPILER-ERROR is HERE
    //pBtns = new Button2;
    for (int i = 0; i < args; ++i) {
        pBtns[i] = Button2(g_btns[i]);
        pBtns[i].setPressedHandler(button_callback);
    }
}
```

I want in the above example that pBtns contains an array with 3 Pointers to new created and initialized objects. Additionaly I want to know what function is ment in the error message. I like the idea of storing objects in arrays and want to use it in my own development, when I understood the principle and practised - so what are the pros and cons of technique?

*(sri for the long text - just don't yet know whats relevant, so pimp my brain!)*

Comment: Where are you learning this stuff from?

Comment: Source of the code [link](https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/T5-Ink-Screen-Series)  So I will do some research on object constructors ... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Button2 *pBtns` is not an array of pointers, but a pointer to one or more actual `Button2` objects. That is why `new[]` tries to construct such objects.

You would need

```
Button2 **pBtns=nullptr;
...
pBtns=new *Button2[args];
```

and then could the loop with `pBtns[i]=new Button2(...);` work.

But this is rather C-ish (minus the use of `new`), contemporary C++ code would more likely use `std::vector`, as comments and other answer(s) suggest.

Comment: You got me! I'm far from understanding the complexity of c++ and still do c in parallel. But I'll give std::vector a try! Now I have a hint how to refine my knowledge. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When an array is allocated, the program will attempt to default construct the elements.

You cannot default construct `Button2` because defining another constructor disables the automatically generated default constructor. You need to either add a default constructor or move to [a smarter container like `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Example:

```
Button2 *pBtns = nullptr;
```

becomes

```
std::vector<Button2> btns;
```

And then later buttons are created in the `vector` with

```
btns.emplace_back(<arguments>);
```

As an added bonus, `vector` removes all of the memory management work that a dynamically allocated array saddles you with.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the lack of default (no argument) constructor called by operator `new []`.

To define one add this line to the `class Button2` definition:

```
Button2() = default; // after C++11
```

or

```
Button2() {} // before C++11
```

Assuming all your members also have default constructors (most likely), this should JustWork(**TM**)

Comment: +1 ,but should address the question of whether or not it makes sense to allow default constructed buttons. There's not enough information in this specific question to make that call, but it's a question the Asker needs to ask themselves before going this route.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree, but he looks like a beginner trying to make an array with Button objects which are initialized in a loop. I too like deleting constructors that leave an object in an invalid/uninitialized state, but it's an overkill in this case imo.

Comment: Agree in return, but it should still be thought over even if the mental discussion goes, "Should I...? Yeah."

Comment: I can confirm that this solution solves the problem right away, but I still want to give std::vector a try.